# exclude certain tags in wp_query and output 20

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

What is wrong with this code:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__not_in' => array( 8,9,10 ) ), 'posts_per_page' => 20 ); ?>
```

I have tried and tried but I cant get it to work

Comment: What's not working about it?  Is is it not working at all, or returning posts but not recognizing your arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posts per page is outside the array and is actually being used as a second parameter to WP_Query.

Change this:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__not_in' => array( 8,9,10 ) ), 'posts_per_page' => 20 ); ?>
```

To:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__not_in' => array( 8,9,10 ), 'posts_per_page' => 20 ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Wow, it was that little typo all along. Thanks so very much Nathan!